# Linq to Entity - Inserting a record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to Linq to Entity (Infact I am new to Linq) and I am struggling to insert a row.

Following a number of tutorials (None of which seem to agree with each other or are very detailed) I managed to come up with the following code but I'm struggling to work out how to use what I have ...

The DB looks like this:

```
namespace IdeaGen.Data
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class IdeaGenEntities : DbContext
{
    public IdeaGenEntities()
        : base("name=IdeaGenEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class NewIdea
{
    public int IdeaID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

(I haven't done the user model yet)

And my controller looks like this but isn't compiling.

```
using (IdeaGenEntities ctx = new IdeaGenEntities())
        {
            var ideas = ctx.Ideas;
            NewIdea idea = new NewIdea();
            idea.Description = model.Description;
            idea.Title = model.Title;
            ctx.Ideas.Add(idea);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Oh and I also use this as per one of the tutorials ...

```
namespace IdeaGen.Data
{
public class DBBase
{
    private IdeaGenEntities _IdeaGenEntity = new IdeaGenEntities();

    public IdeaGenEntities IdeaGenEntity {get {return _IdeaGenEntity; } }
}
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Once I get a foundation understanding of what I am doing I will be able to work the rest out but with nothing to work from I am kinda in the dark about where I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Got it thanks to user user619656. My updated Controller looks like this ...

```
        IdeaGenEntities ctx = new IdeaGenEntities();
        Idea Idea = new Idea();
        Idea.Title = model.Title;
        Idea.Description = model.Description;
        ctx.Ideas.Add(Idea);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the compilation error? You haven't shown where 'model' is declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ideas` is a `DbSet<Idea>` and you can only add `Idea` objects to this collection.

But here

```
NewIdea idea = new NewIdea();
idea.Description = model.Description;
idea.Title = model.Title;
ctx.Ideas.Add(idea);
```

you are adding a NewIdea object to Ideas, and that's where you get the error.